# Where are Gradle detailed logs when building Flutter application in debug mode?

Tags: gradle, flutter

I am debugging my Flutter application and sometimes I get Gradle build errors. That's fine, some configuration is incorrect.

However it is difficult to find the actual problem as the debug console is not displaying any details, such as which row is breaking the build.

There's no error trace.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\<USER>\Projects\<app>\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

  Command: C:\Users\<USER>\Projects\<APP>\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Where, or how, can I see the Gradle logs when building a Flutter application in debug mode?

Here is a print too.

[image]

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Comment: @Yster None. We found the actual error in the gradle file and fixed it, but still the error logs show nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You should edit your `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` file by adding:

```
org.gradle.console=verbose
```

and run

```sh
flutter run -v
```

Here a piece of output in VSCode
[image]

Comment: You're Chinese's old friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Android part of your project with AndroidStudio to help you understand the gradle errors.

With IntelliJ or VSCode, you just have to right click on android folder and click "Open in Android Studio"

Comment: I opened Android Studio but the option to build or run the App is disabled. There's no errors in my project also.

Comment: I tried running it manually, but the process end almost immediately and theres no output: `android>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
android>gradlew.bat app:properties
android>`